# How to get information from Google Sheets to send it via form emailer?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I created a Google Form. There is a field called email. With this I can receive emails from the submitter. I want to send them a confirmation email taking some information from the sheet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need a [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) for this, triggered by form submission and using the method [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) to send email (it's preferable to use `MailApp` over `GmailApp`, so that the script is only authorized to send email, not to read or modify the contents of your inbox.)

For example, suppose this is the sheet with form submissions, where I added column Confirmed to keep track of what's been confirmed already.

```
+---+---------------------+----------+----------------+-----------+
|   |          A          |    B     |       C        |     D     |
+---+---------------------+----------+----------------+-----------+
| 1 | Timestamp           | Response | Email          | Confirmed |
| 2 | 10/30/2015 20:19:36 | jjj      | user@gmail.com |           |
+---+---------------------+----------+----------------+-----------+
```

The script given below should have a trigger added from the script editor via Resources > This project's triggers...  Specifically, it should be "from spreadsheet > on form submit".

```
function formEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var width = values[0].length;
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][width-1]) {
      break;
    }
    var email = values[i][2];
    var subject = 'Form submission confirmed';
    var body = 'Your response was: ' + values[i][1];
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
    range.getCell(i+1, width).setValue('yes');
  }
}
```

This reads the form submissions from bottom up, until the last confirmed one. After each email is sent, the entry in "Confirmed" column is set to 'yes'.